# Infinite Scroll?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

This is my script atm, and it doesn't load more images. I really don't know what i'm doing wrong? I've tried first converting my mysql to pdo, it loads the first set of images, but when i visit my website, it already says, "No more content" at top, and can't scroll to infinite.

```
See the new code!
```

**EDIT**

Oke so I did it step by step and this doesn't work well. I tried it like this:

```
$result2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM scroll_images ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?");
$result2->execute(array($set_limit));
```

Doesn't work, only when I use it like this:

```
$result2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM scroll_images ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $set_limit");
```

Why is that?

**NEW EDIT!**

So the data thing is working, now the index. The first statement works, because it load's the first images. But now the rest of the query for getting all the rows in one query and get it with `FOUND_ROWS()`

Code:

```
$result = $pdo->query("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM scroll_images ORDER BY id ASC limit 12"); // This works, but don't know about the sql_calc_found rows part.

$resultALL = $pdo->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rowcount");
$resultALL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 

$actual_row_count = $resultALL->rowcount; // doesn't return anything.
```

Comment: Does it make any request when you scroll? check your console log to see if there are any error or ajax requests being made

Comment: Posting *both* PHP and JS code is a clear indicator of laziness. Please take the effort to verify that at least one of them is working, and ask a question about the other one.

Comment: It's totally no indicator of laziness, i really don't know what to do now, tested it with echo's my results, it prints out the right stuff, but it doesn't load more. So i can use some tips ;)

Comment: Edit my post! Found one problem.

Comment: `$set_limit` is bound as a string. **Try**
`$result2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM scroll_images ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT ?");
$result2->bindValue(1, $set_limit, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$result2->execute();`

Comment: By trying those things, i've found an Answer to that question. Needed to add an attribute to my pdo statement. Now i have one more question. Check the edit!